# Django - override save method

Tags: python, django

I'm overriding the `save()` method for a model in Django, but it's not working properly.

I want the `book_quantity` to update automatically each time when, I edit the number of books in a cart and click save button.

**For instance:**

I've already changed the number of the book from 0 to 11 and clicked the save button, but the `book_quantity` still showing number 0 (the previous number). If I change the number from 11 to 22 or not change the number then click the save button again. The `book_quantity` will be 11. So it always shows the previous number. But what I want is that the `book_quantity` changes to the correct number immediately each time when I click the save button (once).

[image]

**cart/models.py**

```
class Cart(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    book_quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    total_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.email + '_cart'

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.book_quantity = 0
        books = BooksInCart.objects.filter(cart__user=self.user).values('quantity')
        for i in range(len(books)):
            self.book_quantity += books[i].get('quantity')
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)


class BooksInCart(models.Model):

    cart = models.ForeignKey(Cart, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.book.title
```

**Edit:**

Why am I doing this it because I want the `book_quantity`and `total_price` update each time when I add a `BooksInCart` instance into the cart or edit/delete a `BooksInCart` from the cart. But extending the `save()` method is the only idea I came up with. Is there any other better way to achieve this?

Comment: Refresh the page?

Comment: Don't do that! `.save()` can get *circumvented*. For example with a `Cart.objects.update(..)`. You can use aggregation here to calculate the quantify of books in the chart rather fast.

Comment: you dont' need the book_quantity field in your Cart model. book_quantity holds the result of a simple calculation, such things don't need to be stored in the database.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem sorry not sure how to do it, could you please explain more?

Comment: @e4c5 yeah maybe you're right, but I still need to do the same thing for the total price. How can I make  the total_price field update automatically?

Comment: Same thing: I assume the `Book` model has the price, your total_price is just an aggregation as well. Actually the Django [documentation on aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/) contains an example that's very similar to your case.

Comment: as pointed out by @dirkgroten all you need is a aggregation.

Comment: @e4c5  I see now, but that only works when I do it manually (like in the shell). I want the book_quantity update each time when I create/edit/delete a booksincart instance. Extending the save method is the only idea I came up with.

Comment: jinx the whole point is that you don't need to do any of this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I not sure about your idea but,

maybe you can try to use signal? everytime when your quantity is changed, it will change the book_quantity. Such as:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

@receiver(post_save, sender=BooksInCart) # the sender is your fix
def update_book_quantity(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    book_quantity = 0
    books = BooksInCart.objects.filter(cart=instance.cart).values('quantity')
    for item in book.iterator():
        book_quantity += item.get('quantity')
    instance.update(book_quantity=book_quantity)
    # TODO
```

**Meanwhile, I agree with such things don't need to be stored in the database.**

Frankly speaking, this design is awful and it will case problem when the service is used by many people.

So why not try saving it in cache (try it maybe) or try another solution of your design?

Comment: Actually, what I wanted is that the book_quantity update (or initialised) automatically each time when I create a booksincart instance or edit the or delete a booksincart instance. But extending a save methond is the only idea I came up with.

Comment: @Jinx I suggest you can try this way. Only thing to you need to add is a same function of post_delete，or just overwrtie the save function of BooksInCart(the same logic as signal) after self.cart.save() I think

Comment: I'll try that out now.