# django - While using get_user_model for user creation

Tags: python, django

How do I override the `.save()` method for the model which uses `get_user_model`?

`forms.py`

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django import forms

class UserCreateForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        fields = ("first_name", "last_name", "username", "email", "password1", "password2")
        model = get_user_model()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["username"].label = "Username"
        self.fields["email"].label = "Email address"
```

On creation of user I want to send user data into another model. As it has no written model (rather I'm importing it as `from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model`), how do I override the save method like-

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Model, self).save()
        Record.objects.create(
        employee_ID = self.employee_ID,
        first_name = self.first_name,
        last_name = self.last_name)
```

where my Record model is -

```
class Record(models.Model):

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    employee_ID = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
```

Comment: You cannot override and should not monkey-patch a third-party model's save method. Rather connect a handler to the [post_save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/signals/#post-save) signal. There, you have access to the User model (`sender`) and the instance (`instance`).

Comment: @schwobaseggl https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52177182/django-how-to-use-signals

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/signals/#connecting-receiver-functions, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/signals/#connecting-to-signals-sent-by-specific-senders, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719038/where-should-signal-handlers-live-in-a-django-project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try to use `AbstractUser` in django by

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
```

and add a line in your `settings.py`

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "myapp.NewUser"
```

Inherited django user and add override the save method

```
class NewUser(AbstractUser):
    # your code
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Model, self).save()
        Record.objects.create(
        employee_ID = self.employee_ID,
        first_name = self.first_name,
        last_name = self.last_name)
```

and this isn't a right way to create `Record` and it will make your code more complex. Please try [signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/signals/) in django.

you can use `User` as your sender by

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

More about User please read the [document](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/default/#user-objects)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52177182/django-how-to-use-signals thid did'nt work

Comment: @JohnRichards https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51949189/django-override-save-method/51950770#51950770 I think it should work.

Comment: you're not getting my whole point here, there's no model to set it as a sender here.

Comment: @JohnRichards I'm sorry ... What about this one `from django.contrib.auth.models import User
` and use `User` as a sender?

Comment: But each time when the admin/`is_staff` logs in, a new record is getting created? How do stop that?

Answer (score 0):

Use Signals,

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
import Record

def send_data(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):

    record = Record()
    record.employee_ID = instance.username
    record.first_name = instance.first_name
    ....


post_save.connect(receiver = send_data, sender= User)
```